# javascript loop with prompt

Tags: javascript, loops, prompt

I'm having trouble doing a loop with javascript. It's just a game of rock paper scissors. Instead of printing the results of each game one by one, the prompt appears and asks the user three times for their selection. All the results a printed in one go.

How do I get it so that results are printed to the screen after each prompt?

```
function game() {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    selection = prompt("Please enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors:");
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML +=
      "<br /> You picked: " + selection;
    computer = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1);
    if (computer == 1) {
      computerGuess = "Rock";
    } else if (computer == 2) {
      computerGuess = "Scissors";
    } else if (computer == 3) {
      computerGuess = "Paper";
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML +=
      "<br /> Computer picked: " + computerGuess;
    if (selection == "Rock") {
      if (computerGuess == "Rock") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You won!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Scissors") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You lost!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Paper") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "Draw!";
      }
    } else if (selection == "Scissors") {
      if (computerGuess == "Rock") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You lost!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Scissors") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "Draw!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Paper") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You won!";
      }
    } else if (selection == "Paper") {
      if (computerGuess == "Rock") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You won!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Scissors") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You lost!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Paper") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "Draw!";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A prompt inside a loop is blocking, your not giving the UI any time to update.  Prompts are really bad UI, I would avoid using them.  But if you want this to work, one solution is remove the for loop, and use a `setTimeout` at the end to ask the next question...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function game() {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        selection = prompt("Please enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors:");
      
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML +=
      "<br /> You picked: " + selection;
    computer = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1);
    if (computer == 1) {
      computerGuess = "Rock";
    } else if (computer == 2) {
      computerGuess = "Scissors";
    } else if (computer == 3) {
      computerGuess = "Paper";
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML +=
      "<br /> Computer picked: " + computerGuess;
    if (selection == "Rock") {
      if (computerGuess == "Rock") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You won!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Scissors") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You lost!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Paper") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "Draw!";
      }
    } else if (selection == "Scissors") {
      if (computerGuess == "Rock") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You lost!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Scissors") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "Draw!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Paper") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You won!";
      }
    } else if (selection == "Paper") {
      if (computerGuess == "Rock") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You won!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Scissors") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "You lost!";
      } else if (computerGuess == "Paper") {
        document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML += "Draw!";
      }
    }
    }, 0);
    
  }
}
game()
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```